# Servlet how to go to next/previous page on button submit

Tags: servlets

New to doing servlets and I'm trying to get my next and previous buttons to work so when I click on next button it will go to a page I specified on println.

Here's my code at the moment.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if(session == null){
            session = request.getSession(true);
            out.println("<html>\n" + 
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<form method = \"post\">\n" +
                    "userid: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\">\n" +
                    "<br />\n" +
                    "password: <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\">\n" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" name=\"log_in\">\n" +
                    "</form></body></html>");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if(request.getParameter("log_in") != null){
        out.println("<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<img src=\"images/0.jpg\">\n" +
                "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Previous\" name=\"prev\">\n" +
                "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Next\" name=\"next\">\n" +
                "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"lol\" name=\"lol\">\n" +
                "</body></html>");
        if(request.getParameter("next") != null){
            out.println("<html>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<img src=\"images/0.jpg\">\n" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Previous\" name=\"prev\">\n" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Next\" name=\"next\">\n" +
                    "</body></html>");
        }
    }
}
}
```

So right now when I click next nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the `web.xml` file along with any relevant UI code.

Comment: in doGet method, where have you declared HttpSession object? you are directly using session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the url for your servlet in this form action attribute in order to submit the form using post, back to the servlet and have the request handled with doPost.:

```
<form method = \"post\" action = \"/my-servlet-mapping\">
```

In order to make the next/previous buttons to work, you need to wrap them in a form element like this:

```
"<form method = \"post\" action = \"/my-servlet-mapping\">\n" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Previous\" name=\"prev\">\n" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Next\" name=\"next\">\n" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"lol\" name=\"lol\">\n" +
"</form>"
```

So that they submit back to the servlet and be handled by the doPost method.

The same applies to the for where you handling the "next" case.